# htaccess getting additional php arguments

Tags: php, .htaccess, arguments, parameter-passing

My .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?key=$1
```

My **index.php** code given below

```
<?php

$key=isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : 'home';
if( in_array( $key, array('home','about','terms') ) ){
   include("$key.php");
}else{
   include("profile.php");
}
?>
```

When is using "http://localhost/project_dir/home" is working correctly(home is assigned to argument '?key'). but i want to pass extra arguments like "http://localhost/project_dir/home?a=abc123"

How can i get argument "a"(`$_GET['a']` ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) - [in particular, `QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

> **QSA|qsappend**
>
> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.
>
> Consider the following rule:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [QSA]
> ```
>
> With the [QSA] flag, a request for `/pages/123?one=two` will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123&one=two`. Without the [QSA] flag, that same request will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123` - that is, the existing query string will be discarded.
>
> > <sub>Apache manual, © 2016 The Apache Software Foundation, Apache License 2.0</sub>

So change your `.htacess` rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?key=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben. working fine